# How to make rdlc report from xml string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, reporting, reportviewer

Im trying to make a report viewer (RDLC REPORT) with xml string as data source using asp.net c#
This is the xml

```
"<Data><Result>success</Result><Rowset><Row><Date>08-09-2020</Date><TrNo>2015</TrNo><Debit>355</Debit><Credit></Credit><Remark>rem in 2020015-500 USD/Commession</Remark><Balance>-809.5</Balance></Row></Rowset></Data>"
```

So i have added a dataset called st_DS

[this is a photo for the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhY6g.png)

also created a rdlc report
[rdlc report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eErlx.png)

i have added the following line of code

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  
      <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

and this is the code behind

```
string xml_resp = objCmd.Parameters["p_out"].Value.ToString();  
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml_resp));  
        st_DS stt = new st_DS();  
        stt.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml_resp)));   
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;  
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("st.rdlc");  
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();             
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("st_DS",stt.Tables[0])); 
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

when i run the code it gives me a blank report with no data as
[the text inside the red box is the response i got (XML)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPzTP.png)

any one can help me with this ,im so confused ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the solution
simply add the following dataset

```
 Dataset ds = new Dataset();
    ds.ReadXml(new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(xml_resp)));
     ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("st_DS", ds.Tables["Row"]);
```

i have to merge the 2 datasets at the report DataSource to make it works !